# Large number of TextViews a performance hit? Should I switch to ListView instead of using Scrollview?

Tags: android, performance, listview, scrollview

So I have a screen that displays a grid (TableView where each TableRow is mostly TextViews) like a scorecard, with like 8 rows and 11 columns.

I'd like to add about 10 more rows to it, and keep it in a ScrollView. But I'm wondering if I should switch the whole thing to a ListView.

So assuming that half my grid is "off screen" is there a big performance (rendering time, memory usage) hit to just using the ScrollView? Or would I be better off going to a ListView?

Basically I just don't want the thing to lag when it displays the screen for the first time (or during scrolling).

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind when answering, that I'm aware of the performance benefits of the ListView, but really want to know if it will make a large difference in my case. Also keep in mind that  the rows in my grid are not all identical, so there would be a trade off where I may end up with some fairly complex Adapter class to manage how each row in the list is displayed (if rowx then do this, if rowy then do this, etc, etc).

Comment: A problem with the ListView approach is that what I have right now is a TableLayout with a bunch of TableRows. You can't really achieve the same results (cells resizing so that all columns are aligned perfectly) easily with a listview. So given that I want some TableView functionality here, perhaps ListView is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a ListView... It's so comfortable

With a ListView you can easily manage the selected rows. And with the right Adapter you can also write a very efficent List.

You can find a few examples in the [Android API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html)

Comment: @kyp->Right, I've used ListViews before, but actually find them a bit less straight forward than desired when doing certain things. For instance if you have rows that you want slightly different than others you have to do more complex logic in your Adapter.getView method, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using ListView and ListAdapter, there is a lot that is done under the hood to ensure that it is efficient, for example, the displayed list items are reused when scrolling rather than creating one for every item.

So yes, I would suggest using ListView along with ListAdapter.